# How can I create a Next.js API endpoint that gets realtime updates from Supabase database

Tags: next.js, server-side, supabase

I'm creating a Chrome extension using Next.js and Plasmo, and Plasmo has this weird thing where I'm unable to import Supabase on the client side, so I'm creating custom api routes in the `page/api` folder to handle anything that has to do with Supabase. I've been stuck on trying to implement realtime updates - the expected behavior is for request to return no response until the API has been updated, and then when the API updates, we get whatever the payload is and then stop.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import supabase from "scripts/config/supabaseClient";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { message_id } = req.query;

  const channel = supabase.channel("my-channel");
  console.log("waiting for change");

  channel.on(
    "postgres_changes",
    {
      event: "UPDATE",
      schema: "public",
      table: "messages",
      filter: `id=eq.${message_id}`
    },
    (payload) => {
      console.log(payload);
      channel.unsubscribe()
      res.status(200).json(payload);
    }
  );
  console.log("subscription done");
};
```

However, right now, what's happening is I'm getting this error: `API resolved without sending a response for /api/supabase/subscriber?message_id=hey, this may result in stalled requests.` The `"waiting for change"` and `"subscription done"` console.log outputs still show, but the code in the middle doesn't seem to run. I've checked that I've allowed the messages table to broadcast realtime updates.

Comment: You simply cannot do it. Next.js API routes does not support web sockets. https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#websockets